# Using many external svg clippaths in firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

### The problem

I'm trying to crop two images to some triangle shape via clippath, but when I try to move the inline svg code to an external file, only the `fp` clippath applies to the image. The image with the `sp` path disappears completely.

Please note that I'm using Firefox and therefore cannot use pure css and the `clip-path: polygon()` style.

## The SVG code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="fp">
            <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 0 100"/>
        </clipPath>

        <clippath id="sp">
            <polygon points="100 0, 100 100, 0 100"/>
        </clippath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

### The working fiddle

This fiddle works because it's inline SVG. Try to move it to a separate file and refer to it in the css. It won't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/qkqovjmq/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the [jQuery clip path plugin](https://github.com/andrusieczko/clip-path-polygon) which renders all clip paths correctly.